# jQuery to vertically center text only loads after page resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have the following jQuery to vertically center text next to an image but it only loads after the page is re-sized.

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $(function () {
        var changeheight = function () {
            $('.vertical-align').height($('.featurette-image').height());
        }
        $(window).on('resize', function () {
            if ($(window).width() > 765) {
                changeheight();
            } else {
                $('.vertical-align').height('auto');
            }
        })
    })
});
```

Comment: The only place `changeheight()` gets called is in the resize event.  This is surprising?

Comment: thank you. idk how i missed that.

Answer (score 1):

Remove window resize and should work on load

```js
$(window).load(function() {
   var changeheight = function() {
     $('.vertical-align').height($('.featurette-image').height());
   }
     if ($(window).width() > 765) {
       changeheight();
     } else {
       $('.vertical-align').height('auto');
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Idk why OP deleted his answer but it was correct. I had to remove window resize

The following code is correct:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  var changeheight = function() {
    $('.vertical-align').height($('.featurette-image').height());
  }
  if ($(window).width() > 765) {
    changeheight();
  } else {
    $('.vertical-align').height('auto');
  }
});
```